# Convert explicit type to var in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, var, java-10

I have a Java 10 project with the following code:

```
Map<String, String> map = method();
```

When I put the cursor on `Map...` and press `Alt+Enter`, there should be an option "Replace explicit type with `var`". However, this option is missing from my menu.

How to enable this option? Should I clean some caches or something?

I'm using IDEA 2018.1.1 EAP.

Comment: This is a pure speculation but cases of declaration + assignment from method return value usually tend to fall into the "not obvious to reader" category of type inference and therefore may not be offered by the IDE. This may be configurable (if it isn't, you should probably give this as feedback to Jetbrains).

Comment: What's your `method()` signature? Try something simpler like `int x = 5`. Is language level in project settings set to 10?

Comment: @TagirValeev `Map<String, String> method()`. `int x = 5` doesn't help. The language level is 10 (`var` is working if I type it manually).

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this issue on 2018.1.  I assume your code is in a local scope?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov *there should be an option* ...assuming JetBrains claims it to be, I would suggest to please update the question with the source to make it more meaningful.

Comment: Moreover, I do second the comment from @JacobG., confirming I am using 2018.1 CE which gives me an option to `Replace explicit type with 'var'`. So could be a bug with their update?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov It looks like the answer from Bas solved your problem. If so, can you accept that answer? Doing that makes it easier for other users who may get the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Replace explicit type with 'var'" quick fix is provided by the `Java | Java language level migration aids | Java 10 | Local variable type can be omitted` inspection. Please check if you have this inspection enabled in your settings. It is not enabled automatically if you have the "Disable new inspections by default" setting enabled.

Comment: Thanks. This enabled the quick fix. I also changed the severity of the inspection from "Warning" to "No highlighting, only fix" to avoid unnecessary highlighting of every variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3, when auto-completing or when extracting a variable with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, there's a gear icon next to the generated variable.

[image: extract-variable]

Clicking the gear or using this shortcut <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> will bring a popup that allow to define the wanted behavior for this variable extraction and the next ones.

[image]

---

Adapt these shortcut to your active key map in IntelliJ.